# Change default image editor in only one folder

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, file-association

I've recently made the switch from traditional to digital art, and I have two folders: one where I edit images in photoshop and another where I keep a gallery of "finished" art. My question is, is there a way to have .jpg files open automatically in photoshop ONLY in the one of these two folders (it takes a while to start up and is not ideal for simply looking through or showing off my work).

Comment: You can not. File associations is per-user feature = profile wide. Add a new user.